# Mystery: Rails installed but not detected -- RVM 2.1.5 fixes it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm

When I run:

```
$ rails -v
```

I get:

```
Rails 4.1.8
```

Which means Rails is installed right? However whenever I cd into my app's directory and run Rails, I get:

```
Rails is not currently installed on this system. To get the latest version, simply type:

$ sudo gem install rails
```

I found the solution below but really wanted to understand why:

```
$ rvm use ruby-2.1.5
$ gem install nokogiri -- --use-system-libraries
```

Anyone know? Really appreciate your help!

Comment: Do you have .ruby-version file in your project root directory?

Answer (score 0):

The `Rails 4.1.8` you installed has been installed in the root directory. But when you `cd` into a particular folder it cannot detect the rails in that folder. So you have to create a `.rvmrc` file in your `app` directory and write this

```
rvm use ruby-2.1.2
rvm gemset use "name of the gemset you want to create"
```

Then for this particular gemset install the `rails` you want to install as well as all the gems under this gemset.

You can read more about using it here [Rvm use](https://rvm.io/gemsets/using).